# json decode - getting single array from object?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json file which I decode using json_decode. The json file is an object which holds two arrays. I only want the first array but I'm having trouble figuring out how.

Json file

```
{
   "app":{
      "available":{
         "stats":[
            {
               "name":"the name",
               "at":"url"
            },
            {
               "name":"the name",
               "at":"url"
            }
         ],
         "stats2":[
            {
               "name":"the name",
               "at":"url"
            },
            {
               "name":"the name",
               "at":"url"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I use

```
foreach($data3['app']['available'] as $name => $value)
{
    foreach($value as $entry)
    {
        echo $entry['name'];
    }
}
```

The output I get every name from both stats1 and stats2 arrays. I only want the names from stats1 array, not stats2. How can this be achieved?

Comment: there was an error in your JSON. after status, : was missing. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because there are two arrays in app->available: stats and stats2

If you are interested in only stats, why don't you try:

```
foreach($data3['app']['available']['stats'] as $name => $value)
```

**__UPDATE__**

Try this one please

```
$in = '{"app":{"available":{"stats": [{"name":"the name","at":"url"},{"name":"the name", "at":"url"}],"stats2":[{"name":"the name","at":"url"},{"name":"the name","at":"url"}]}}}';

$obj = (array) json_decode($in, true);

foreach($obj['app']['available']['stats'] as $value)
{
foreach($value as $e => $v)
    {
     echo ($value['name'] );
     echo ("\r");
    }

}
```

Comment: I forgot to say, I already tried that. For some reason, entry['name'] outputs nothing when I do that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant echo $entry['name'] outputs only a single character, the first letter of the string for some reason, when doing your suggestion.

Comment: Using your update correctly outputs the stats1 array only which is good but I'm still unable to retrieve the "name" string. echo ($value[$e]['name'] ); returns the first character only.